# How to use Itempipeline in scrapy for saving items in database

Tags: python, django

I have this code in `parse_items` in my spider

```
 def parse_items(self, response):

        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select("//li[@class='mod-result-entry  ']")
        items = []


        for site in sites[:2]:
            item = MyItem()
            item['title'] = myfilter(site.select('dl/a').select("string()").extract())
            item['company'] = myfilter(site.select('dl/h2/em').select("string()").extract())
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Now i want to save the items in dtabase using Django models. One way which is working fine si that i simpy use like this

```
item = MYapp.MyDjangoItem()
item.title = myfilter(site.select('dl/a').select("string()").extract())
item.save()
```

now this is working fine

Now i want to know that is that method fine for saving in database .

I mean why we need itempipeline thing which is described in scrapy. Is there any advantage for this.

Fir e,g this is my pipleline

```
class MyPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.ids_seen = set()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
       Myitem = Myapp.DjamgoItem()
       Myitem.title = item['title']
       MyItem.save()
```

is that alright

Also how will my code will call this pipeline. i am confused with this

Answer (score 2):

The pipeline can be useful for sanitizing common values. This is especially useful if you only have one type of object. Saving your django model instance via the pipeline is fine, the example in the scrapy documentation does the same by adding a JsonWriter to the pipeline. (which in real life is unnecessary because there's builtin functionality for that)

*thinking out loud:*

However, when you are creating several objects you probably want to differentiate your processing. Because the spider is passed as an argument to the process_item function this is easy, but (imo), this tends to get rather verbose:

```
class MyPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
       if spider == 'A':
           if item.somefield:
               #... etc
       elif spider == 'B':
           #... etc
```

Personally I like the idea behind form cleaning in Django (checking for an existing function by a field's name prepended with 'clean_'). To achieve similar functionality in scrapy I extended the Item class:

```
class ExtendedItem(Item):
    def _process(self):
        [getattr(self, func)() for func in dir(self) if func.split('_')[-1] in self.fields and callable(getattr(self, func))]
```

So now you can do something like:

```
class Book(ExtendedItem):
    title = Field()

    def _process_title(self):
        title = self['title'].lower()
        self.update(title=title)
```

You could use your pipeline to call item._process() in this case.

*Disclaimer*

I suggested this idea at [github.com](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/197) a while ago. There are probably better implementations (code-wise).